# Где взять scid для Яндекс.Кассы

Tags: яндекс-касса

Не могу найти **scid**. В документации https://yandex.ru/support/checkout/merchant/settings.html#settings__all-purpose-params приведен пример, где его взять, но у меня личный кабинет выглядит по-другому, там нет **scid**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании магазина был выбран способ подключения через API, поэтому scid не требуется, нужен только shopID и API ключ, которые есть в личном кабинете. scid использовался в старом способе подключения, чтобы его использовать нужно дать заявку менеджеру через личный кабинет.